# Change option of sass-loader in vue.config

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

I am confused how to change `sass-loader` settings using `vue.config` [in this documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass) there is a `webpack.config` but my project doesn't have one and I don't think I should have one because according to [this documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced) I should use `vue.config`.

The command `vue inspect` contains the string `loader: 'sass-loader',` 8 times so I'm not sure what to change.

My source code is the following:

```css
    <style lang="scss">
      .some-class {
        border-bottom: 100px solid $alert;
      }
    </style>
```

Then I would like to adjust the values for `webpack` using `vue.config` to:

```js
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        prependData: '$alert: ' + process.env.ALERT_COLOR + ';',
      }
    }
```

I suspect I have to change the following entry (coming from `vue inspect`):

```js
    /* config.module.rule('scss').oneOf('vue-modules') */
    {
      resourceQuery: /module/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'vue-style-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            shadowMode: false
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            importLoaders: 2,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            implementation: {
              run_: function() {
                        return _call(f, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                      },
              render: function() {
                        return _call(f, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                      },
              renderSync: function() {
                        return _call(f, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                      },
              info: 'dart-sass\t1.23.0\t(Sass Compiler)\t[Dart]\ndart2js\t2.5.1\t(Dart Compiler)\t[Dart]',
              types: {
                Boolean: function() {
                          return _call(f, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                        },
                Color: function() {
                          return _call(f, this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                        },
                List: function() {
                          return _call(f, this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                        },
                Map: function() {
                          return _call(f, this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                        },
                Null: function() {
                          return _call(f, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                        },
                Number: function() {
                          return _call(f, this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                        },
                String: function() {
                          return _call(f, this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
                        },
                Error: function Error() { [native code] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the docs you linked I would guess it's something like this:

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const cssRule = config.module.rule('css')

    // clear all existing loaders.
    // if you don't do this, the loader below will be appended to
    // existing loaders of the rule.
    cssRule.uses.clear()

    // add replacement loader(s)
    cssRule
      .use('sass-loader')
        .loader('sass-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          // modify the options...
          return options
        })
  }
}
```

And add the `sass` options you want were is says `modify the options`.

It's worth noting that `cssRule.uses.clear()` will clear the previous CSS rules. Which I think you will need to do otherwise you might have conflicting rules. If you find that it is removing a rule you need, I would add it back manually (the same way you are adding `sass`.

Comment: I cannot confirm if that works but I went with [this solution](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/). Thank you for your answer and I'll give it a go later and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, in my vue.config

const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "Theme/_colors.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        Theme: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          `src/themes/${process.env.THEME || 'light'}/`
        ),
      },
   },
  },
};
```

In `_colors.css` I can just set the variables: `$alert:red;`